# Didn't recieve badges?

Tags: support

I just used up all 40 of my votes for today, and I expected(ok, anticipated) to receive the "suffrage" and "vox populi" badges; please help? I know I used all of them up because when I go to vote on another one it says "Daily vote limit reached..."

Comment: Sometimes it takes a few hours for new badges to show up. These particular badges might wait for the end of the day to be awarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ThaddeusB said, the voting badges are not awarded immediately, so that's why you didn't get the Suffrage badge right away.  However, the reason you didn't get the Vox Populi badge is a little more complex.

In order to get the Vox Populi badge, it's not merely a matter of voting until you hit the limit.  You actually have to vote 40 times, and you don't automatically get 40 votes per day.

The details are explained in a Meta Stack Exchange post ([What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/300411)), but the short version is:

- You get 30 general purpose votes a day (for question or answers)
- You get 10 question-only votes a day
- If you use up all your general purpose votes on answers first, you won't get the opportunity to use your question-only votes

So if you don't vote for 10 questions early in your voting spree, you'll hit the daily limit before voting 40 times, and you won't get the Vox Populi badge.

Answer (score 8):

The voting badges aren't awarded until the end of the day.